# How to show generated JS in Clojurescript REPL?

Tags: javascript, emacs, read-eval-print-loop, clojurescript

In [this presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enwIIGzhahw#t=32m13s) on core.async Timothy Baldridge c[onnects to a ClojureScript Browser](https://github.com/halgari/clojure-conj-2013-core.async-examples/blob/master/src/clojure_conj_talk/core.clj#L563) REPL and sends generated JavaScript to a web browser from Emacs.

When I work through the [Austin (Clojurescript REPL) steps](https://github.com/cemerick/austin/tree/master/browser-connected-repl-sample) here I don't get generated JavaScript as I see in the video. What am I missing?

My question is: **How to show generated JS in Clojurescript REPL?**

Answer (score 2):

If you evaluate the clojure[script] code in [emacs-cider](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider) through `C-c C-e         nrepl-eval-last-expression` with BREPL enabled you will have the same effect.

Also you can reuse the same code for this https://github.com/halgari/clojure-conj-2013-core.async-examples

Pay attention that you have to load first this directives

```
(require 'cljs.repl.browser)

(cemerick.piggieback/cljs-repl
  :repl-env (cljs.repl.browser/repl-env :port 9000))
```

Then reload the browser and try this to confirm you are connected

```
(js/alert "We're running ClojureScript")
```

You will have an alert in your browser

Here is the project.clj definition of Timothy Baldridge Conference

```
(defproject clojure-conj-talk "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.0-alpha2"]]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.256.0-1bf8cf-alpha"]
                 [http-kit "2.1.10"]
                 [cheshire "5.2.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2014"]
                 [com.cemerick/austin "0.1.3"]]
  :profiles {:dev {:repl-options {:init-ns user}
                   :plugins [[com.cemerick/austin "0.1.0"]
                             [lein-cljsbuild "0.3.2"]]
                   :cljsbuild {:builds [{:source-paths ["src-cljs"]
                                         :compiler {:output-to "app.js"
                                                    :optimizations :simple
                                                    :pretty-print true}}]}}})
```